# Falsi regula using maple

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, nonlinear-optimization, maple

Hi I'm using falsi regula algorithm in maple. For first function it worked fine :

> restart;
>   epsilon := 1e-3:
>   f := x->x^3+x^2-3:
>    a:= 1:
>    b:=2:
>    step:=infinity:
>    while abs(step) >= epsilon or( abs(f(a)) >= epsilon and abs(f(b)) >= epsilon) do
>        c := (f(a)*b - f(b)*a)/(f(a) - f(b));
>        if f(c) = 0 then
>         break;
>       elif f(a)*f(c) < 0 then
>   step:=b-c:
>          b := c;
>       else
>   step:=a-c;
>          a := c;
>       fi;
>   od:
>   evalf([a, b]);

```
                      [1.174421025, 2.]
```

but I've problem with two another functions when using the same code :

> restart;
>   epsilon := 1e-3:
>   f := x->exp(x)-x^2:
>   a:= -1:
>   b:=0:
>   step:=2:
>   while abs(step) >= epsilon or( abs(f(a)) >= epsilon and abs(f(b)) >= epsilon) do
>       c := evalf((f(a)*b - f(b)*a)/(f(a) - f(b));
>          if (f(a)*f(c)) < 0 then
>   step:=b-c:
>          b := c;
>       else
>   step:=a-c;
>          a := c;
>       fi;
>   od:
>   I got error: cannot evaluate boolean, the same situation for f:=x->x-sin(x)-0.25;. Can anyone help me with this problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default inequality comparators in Maple will not deal with transcendental numbers such as **exp(1)** and **sin(1)**. You need to convert these numbers to floating point with **evalf**. You can change the definition of **f** from **x->** *whatever* to **x-> evalf(** *whatever* **)**.

Comment: Thanks for helping me :) Now it works perfectly !